# Is it considered bad design to combine the adjancey list model and the nested sets model?

Tags: mysql, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I'm working on building a tree structure in MySQL and have been experimenting with different ways of representing the data.  However, no matter how I slice it, there are shortcomings.

The nested sets model allows me to easily select entire branches of the tree - which I need to do.  However it is not so easy to select immediate children of a node.

The adjacency list model is great for getting immediate children, but not so good for returning entire branches of the tree.

I'm wondering, is there anything particularly bad about building a tree structure like this:

```
TABLE: Tree
    ID
    name
    lft
    rgt
    parentID
```

So what I have is the adjacency list model and the nested sets model all in the same table.  That way I can use either / or, depending on the circumstances of what I am selecting for.

What are peoples' thoughts?  Is this allowed?  (Peanut butter and chocolate together at last?)  Or is this considered bad design?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you also considered building a transitive closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend it myself. This is the style which CakePHP uses for its tree structures, and as you pointed out, it gives you great flexibility. You just need to do a bit more work to ensure the integrity of your tree, but it's quite worth it.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not bad design at all. At least in my opinion.

I would however only implement one. For example, I used Adjacency List Model as my prime method of adding new elements and retreiving.. (obviously retreiving since its so easy) however, I also added parentIds for Nested Set.

The benefit of this is that I can rebuild my ALM at any time and can easily move things quickly providing I keep the parentIds.

I would not **use** both in your code however, just have it there in the background...

## Edited Comments

You mention that it is not so easy to select immediate children. I think you might be doing something wrong. It is extremely easy even in Adjacency List to select the immediate children.

If you create a new question I will answer how to do it in that.

Comment: Well, I need to do a bit more than select immediate children...  If I match a set of nodes using LIKE, I need to select each of those nodes, a comma-delimmited list of the immediate children of each of those nodes, and a comma-delimmited list of the ancestors of each of those nodes.  (!!!)  I'm hoping to do that in a single SQL if possible.  Sure, I'll post that as a new question.  Feel up to a challenge, grin?  :)

Comment: If you provide enough information I will take a look. But it seems quite difficult from your brief description above.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.  I posted the question.

Comment: It's not actually very simple to select immediate children in the Nested Set model. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html and search for "immediate subordinates" on that page.